# Custom memory allocator for real-mode DOS .COM (freestanding) -- how to debug?

Tags: c, memory-management, dos, freestanding

A little background first: stumbling upon [this blog post](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/12/09/), I learned it was possible to create DOS `.COM` files with the GNU linker and it's not even rocket science. Using `clang` and the `-m16` switch (creating *real-mode* compatible 32bit code by prefixing 32bit instructions accordingly), this worked out quite well. So I had the idea to try implementing just enough runtime to get a [little curses game](https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake) I wrote recently to compile to a `.COM` and run in *real-mode* DOS. The game is small enough so that squeezing everything (text, data, bss, heap, stack) in 64KB seemed doable. Of course, it uses `malloc()`. So I had to come up with my own implementation. This is what it looks like:

```
typedef unsigned short size_t; /* from stddef.h */

typedef struct hhdr hhdr;
struct hhdr
{
    void *next;
    int free;
};

extern char _heap;
static char *hbreak = &_heap;
static hhdr hhead = { &_heap, 0 };

static void *newchunk(size_t size)
{
    char *stack;
    __asm__("mov %%esp, %0": "=rm" (stack));
    if (hbreak + size > stack - 0x40) return 0;
    if (size < 1024) size = 1024;
    hhdr *chunk = (hhdr *)hbreak;
    hbreak += size;
    if (hbreak > stack - 0x40) hbreak = stack - 0x40;
    chunk->next = hbreak;
    chunk->free = 1;
    return chunk;
}

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (!size) return 0;
    if (size % sizeof(hhdr)) size += sizeof(hhdr) - (size % sizeof(hhdr));

    hhdr *hdr = &hhead;
    while ((char *)hdr->next < hbreak)
    {
        hdr = hdr->next;
        if (hdr->free && 
                (char *)hdr->next - (char *)hdr - sizeof(hhdr) >= size)
        {
            if ((char *)hdr->next - (char *)hdr - 2*sizeof(hhdr) > size)
            {
                hhdr *hdr2 = (hhdr *)((char *)hdr + sizeof(hhdr) + size);
                hdr2->free = 1;
                hdr2->next = hdr->next;
                hdr->next = hdr2;
            }
            hdr->free = 0;
            return (char *)hdr + sizeof(hhdr);
        }
    }

    if (!(hdr->next = newchunk(size + sizeof(hhdr)))) return 0;
    return malloc(size);
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) return;
    hhdr *hdr = (hhdr *)((char *)ptr - sizeof(hhdr));
    hdr->free = 1;
    if ((void *)hdr != hhead.next)
    {
        hhdr *hdr2 = hhead.next;
        while (hdr2->next != hdr) hdr2 = hdr2->next;
        if (hdr2->free) hdr = hdr2;
    }
    hhdr *next = hdr->next;
    while ((char *)next < hbreak)
    {
        if (!next->free) break;
        hdr->next = next;
        next = next->next;
    }
    if ((char *)next == hbreak) hbreak = (char *)hdr;
}
```

The `_heap` symbol is defined by the linker. Not showing `realloc()` here as it isn't used right now anyways (and therefore completely untested).

The problem now is: I created my [runtime](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos) here (malloc is in src/libdos/stdlib.c), wrote a lot of testing stuff and in the end, everything seemed to work quite well. My game on the other hand is thoroughly tested and checked for invalid memory accesses using `valgrind`. Still, putting both parts together, it just **crashes**. (Try building the game from git with `make -f libdos.mk`, you will need to have llvm/clang installed).

As I experienced a strange *heisenbug* first (I worked around it for now), I guess it COULD be the optimizers fault getting things wrong when compiling for *real mode*, which is indeed uncommon. But I can't be sure, and the next sensitive candidate would be probably my memory management, see above.

Now the tricky question: How would I debug such a thing? With just my own test code, it works very well. I can't compile my game without optimizations because it will exceed 64KB when doing so. Any suggestions? Or can anyone spot something obviously wrong with the above code?

Comment: Minor: Recommend `(hbreak + size > stack - 0x40)` --> `(hbreak + size +0x40 > stack)` to avoid potential underflow.  Also at `(hbreak > stack - 0x40)`.

Comment: As the stack starts at `0xffff` and the code at `0x0100` for `.COM`, this would be a very b0rked situation ;) but nevertheless, might be a good idea in general!

Comment: Could the problem be in reverse?  If stack is `0xFFFF`, might some computations be overflowing? (wrapping -around) given 16-bit `unsigned`?  If so, use 32-bit unsigned as in `1UL*hbreak + size +0x40 > stack` - just an idea.

Comment: Hmmm ... it doesn't make sense to have a `size_t` bigger than 16 bits because addresses greater than `0xffff` are invalid in *real mode* (you'd have to use segment registers, of course `clang` doesn't support this). But still, pointers *are* 32bit, so the expression should be calculated in 32bit anyways. With some constructed test code, my `malloc()` failed as soon as reaching the stack area, as expected ...

Comment: 1) If isn't that `size_t` is 16-bits, my concern is that math of `hbreak + size +0x40` has a 17-bit answer.  2): Rather than use with the heap pointer, create a global `mem[N]` where N is about as large as reasonable/possible leaving enough stack for the code.  Use `mem` for your memory pool.  Effectively this is about the same as using the heap but with less `asm` tricks`.  3) In real mode and .COM, thought all pointers are 16-bit (same code, data,stack segment).

Comment: @chux thanks for your ideas. To 1) As far as I understand, this shouldn't matter, because I use the whole (32bit) `esp` register to compare with. Could there be "junk" in the upper 16 bits? :o 2) I didn't initially try a statically allocated memory pool because I wanted to stay as generic as possible (so, not pre-determining the size of the heap) ... but I'll give it a try and see whether it behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

If this is real mode DOS, I'm not sure about the upper bits of esp. As for `malloc()`, use the memory between `ss:sp and 0xa000:0000`, the memory between the top of the stack and the `640k` boundary . I don't recall if MS-DOS allocates all of the 640k region for a .COM program or not. There are two DOS calls, `INT 21H, ah = 04Ah releases memory, ah = 048H allocates memory`, but I don't recall if these are for .COM or .EXE programs.

Comment: Wait, for `.COM`, `cs` == `ds` == `es` and using `clang`, I have no way to access memory in any other segment (except through inline assembly of course), so I'm using *just* 64KB here. Why allocate memory from DOS that you can't use in C anyways? The heap starts wherever sections placed by the linker end (right now around `[ds]:8300`) and the stack starts (in the same segment) from `[ds]:ffff`.

Comment: With Microsoft compiler, you can use __far to access the memory outside the current data segment. For example char __far *fpchar;